# $L^p$ integrability condition

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove an equivalent condition for functions belonging in $L^p$. It's convergence of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}2^{np}m(|f|>2^n)$. the one direction is an easy application of Chebyshev's inequality. However I am having trouble with the reverse direction. that is whenever the series converges, then $\|f\|_p<+\infty$.

Comment: Belonging to $ L^p $ you mean?  You wrote $ L^r $ in your post but the condition has $ p $ so I assume you meant $ p $ all along.

Comment: Yes! fixed, thank you. I believe $p$ is more standard so lets stick with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ A_n = \{ |f| > 2^n \} $ so the sequence of sets $ A_n $ is decreasing.  Define $ B_n = A_n \backslash A_{n+1} $.  On $ B_n $ we have $ 2^n < |f| \leq 2^{n+1} $.  Define $ \psi $ by $ \psi(x) = 2^{n+1} $ on each $ B_n $, i.e.
$$
\psi = \sum_n {2^{n+1} \chi_{B_n}}
$$.  Now $ \psi $ dominates $ |f| $ and we have
$$
\int {|f|^p} \leq \int \psi^p = 2^p \sum_n {2^{np}|B_n|} \leq 2^p \sum_n {2^{np} \mu A_n} < \infty
$$
as desired.

Comment: $\psi$ cannot dominate $|f|$ outside of $B_n$ as it vanishes

Comment: I mean, for each $ x $, there is a unique $ B_n $ which contains $ x $ (except where $ f(x) = 0 $ where we can take $ \psi(x) = 0 $).  Set $ \psi(x) = 2^{n+1} $ for that unique $ n $.

Comment: Wouldn't $\psi$ be the sum of all $2^{n+1}\chi_{B_n}$ then? Rather than just one of them for a certain $n$.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that, yes, this is what I meant.  I was defining $ \psi $ on the relevant level-sets.

Comment: Thanks! and for the converse direction we have that $2^{pn} m(|f|>2^n)<\|f\|_p$ by Chebyshev, so just summing over $n$ should do it. However I just realized summing the RHS is infinite. how do I get around that